# How do I check if something was 4 days ago in PHP?

Tags: php, unix, time

I am trying to write a function which checks if a "Finished Lesson" was four days ago. How do I check if said lesson was in that time range, for example. If it was finished yesterday, 2 days ago, 3 days ago, 4 days ago, it would be true since it is in the time range of "4 days ago".

How do I check this?

So far I've done:

```
$time = time();

$fourDays = 345600;
$threeDays = 259200;
$lastLesson = $ml->getLesson($cid, $time, true);

$lastLessonDate = $lastLesson['deadline'];
$displayLastLesson = false;
if ($lastLessonDate  + $fourDays < $time)
{
    $displayLastLesson = true;
    //We print lesson that was finished less than 4 days ago
}
else
{
    //We print lesson that is in the next 3 days

}
```

Right now, the if statement keeps hitting true which is not what I want since I have a lesson that was finished on the 3rd May. It should be true for a lesson that was finished on the 7th May I guess?

Comment: What datatype is $finishedLesson['deadline'], is it a unix timestamp?

Comment: When you say 4 days ago, do you mean between exactly 4 days ago and 5 days ago (ie between 1:27pm on the 6:th and 1:27pm on the 7:th) or do you mean anytime during the day on the 6:th?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$time = time();
$fourDays = strtotime('-4 days');
$lastLesson = $ml->getLesson($cid, $time, true);

$lastLessonDate = $finishedLesson['deadline'];
$displayLastLesson = false;
if ($lastLessonDate >= $fourDays && $lastLessonDate <= $time)
{
    $displayLastLesson = true;
    //We print lesson that was finished less than 4 days ago
}
else
{
    //We print lesson that is in the next 3 days

}
```

Comment: Hey, your answer is correct and makes more sense than mine but what is the difference between this:

$lastLessonDate + $fourDays > $time and your if statement ?

Comment: Actually...I found $lastLessonDate + $fourDays > $time to work !

Answer (score 0):

All calculations should be calculated relative to today at 12am, not `time()` which gives you the current time now (e.g. 6pm)  This is an issue because when you do this, 1 day ago (now - 24hours) means time that is between yesterday 6pm and today 6pm. Instead, yesterday should mean a time between yesterday 12am and today 12am.

Below is a simplified calculation to illustrate the idea:

```
$lastLessonDate = strtotime($lastLessonDate);
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); // 12:00am today , you can use strtotime('today') too
$day = 24* 60 * 60;
if($lastLessonDate > $today) // last lesson is more than 12:00am today, meaning today
 echo 'today';
else if($lastLessonDate > ($today - (1 * $day))
 echo 'yesterday';
else if($lastLessonDate > ($today - (2 * $day))
 echo '2 days ago';
else if($lastLessonDate > ($today - (3 * $day))
 echo '3 days ago';
else if($lastLessonDate > ($today - (4 * $day))
 echo '4 days ago';
else
 echo 'more than 4 days ago';
```